# Copy lines from email to Excel into specific array

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am needing to copy some data from emails into a spreadsheet with a VBA, here is how the data is formatted in the email:

> Items/Cost:
>
> *Item Description 1*: $38.88
>
> Quantity: 1
>
> *Item Description 2*: $39.99
>
> Quantity: 1

The Item Description is always different. Here is how I would like the output to be formatted when copied to Excel:

[image: Table]

And here is my current code that I've tried:

```
Sub CopyToExcel()
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWB As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object
Dim xl
Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim vText As Variant
Dim sText As String
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rCount As Long
Dim bXStarted As Boolean
Dim rTime As Date
Const strPath As String = "C:\Tracking.xlsx" 'the path of the workbook

If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
EndIf
On Error Resume Next
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then
    Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    bXStarted = True
End If
On Error GoTo 0
'Open the workbook to input the data
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
xlWB.Sheets(1).Cells.Delete

'Process each selected record
 rCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 'cCount = xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
  For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
    sText = olItem.Body
    rTime = Format(olItem.ReceivedTime, "mmmm d, yyyy")
    vText = Split(sText, Chr(13))
    'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
     rCount = rCount + 1

    'Check each line of text in the message body
    For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1
    
                 
        If InStr(vText(i), "Items/Cost:") Then
            'ParseText = vText(i + 1) & vbCrLf
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = Trim(vText(2))
            vItem = Split(vText(4), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount + 1) = Trim(vText(6))
            vItem = Split(vText(8), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount + 1) = Trim(vItem(1))
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount + 2) = Trim(vText(10))
            vItem = Split(vText(12), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount + 2) = Trim(vItem(1))
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount + 3) = Trim(vText(14))
            vItem = Split(vText(16), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount + 3) = Trim(vItem(1))
            xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount + 4) = Trim(vText(18))
            vItem = Split(vText(20), Chr(58))
            xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount + 4) = Trim(vItem(1))
            
        End If
                
    Next i
    xlWB.Save
Next olItem


Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWB = Nothing
Set xlSheet = Nothing
Set olItem = Nothing


End Sub
```

Also I'm no expert at VB so any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
I figured out how to extract it the way I want to but it's sloppy and not dynamic. Sometimes there are 2 items and sometimes 5, so i need it to be adaptable. Can someone help me clean it up by chance?

Comment: @Om3r your code or mine? Mine does work but is not as adaptable as I need it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
Option Explicit
Sub EmailToCsv()
    Dim olItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim vText As Variant
    Dim sText As String
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowCount As Long
    Dim xlStarted As Boolean
    Dim FilePath As String

    '// Update File location
    FilePath = "C:\Temp\Tracking.xlsx"

    '// Process Selections
    If Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Items selected!", vbCritical, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err <> 0 Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        xlStarted = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    '// Open the workbook to input the data
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '// Process each selected record
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        sText = olItem.Body
        vText = Split(sText, Chr(13)) ' Chr(13)) carriage return

        '// Find the next empty line of the worksheet
        RowCount = xlSheet.Range("A" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        RowCount = RowCount + 1

        '// Check each line of text in the message body
        For i = UBound(vText) To 0 Step -1

            '// Item Description 1
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Item Description 1:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58)) ' Chr(58) ":"
                xlSheet.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Item Description 1: " & Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Quantity
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Quantity:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("B" & RowCount) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Item Description 2
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Item Description 2:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("A" & RowCount + 1) = "Item Description 2: " & Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

            '// Quantity
            If InStr(1, vText(i), "Quantity:") > 0 Then
                vItem = Split(vText(i), Chr(58))
                xlSheet.Range("B" & RowCount + 1) = Trim(vItem(1))
            End If

        Next i
    Next olItem

    '// SaveChanges & Close
    xlWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
    If xlStarted Then
        xlApp.Quit
    End If

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is the "Item Description" is always different with each email, so I cannot have it look for the string "Item Description 1:" I used that as more of a generic placeholder.